# CodeIgniter ip_address() always returns 0.0.0.0

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, session, ip

My `Codeigniter sessions` have been dying a-lot lately. So I went and had a look at my database and I saw that all the sessions have `ip_address` 0.0.0.0 and some have `useragent` 0

So I checked my `$CI->input->ip_address()` function and saw that it always returns 0.0.0.0 event thought `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` returns an IP address that is valid in `$CI->input->valid_ip($ip)`.

Does this have anything to do with my sessions dying?

I also read that sessions tend to die when the `user-data` reaches 4K. It might be part of it as I give every page an ID in the session which is never removed. I think its not the issue because 90% of the activity is via 1 page and `AJAXs` (I already added an AJAX session fix).

EDIT: I am using CI version 2.1.4.

Comment: What is your CI version? Have your CI system folder files been customized? You will have to go to `/system/core/input.php` and find `public function ip_address()` if you are looking to troubleshoot.

Comment: Also, you mentioned the IPs in the DB are assigned 0.0.0.0 so one would think that you are not using the cookie-only route so the 4k limit does not apply to DB sessions.

Comment: I am using CI version 2.1.4 and it hasn't been customized. The only addition to the core that I did is create a 'MY_Session.php' in-order to apply the AJAX session fix.

Comment: Out of curiosity I am interested in your AJAX session fix because I was not able to resolve the RACE condition issue 100% so I reverted back to using `$_SESSION`. I was making about 6 asynchronous calls at once though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9233081/1056799

Comment: Hmm, I did try that fix but it only reduced the frequency of my session issues. I'm honestly not too worried about it though because I found a size-able performance boost by getting away from DB sessions stored in MySQL.

Comment: If you create a `test.php` controller and do not load the `session` library then do you still get 0.0.0.0 from CI's `ip_address()`?

Comment: I need the DB in-order to control users in the system (Kick, push message etc...). and I get 0.0.0.0 even if the sessions library isn't loaded :\

Comment: Oh sorry, I wasn't implying that you should switch but rather just pointing out my failure lol. Have you taken a look at the `/system/core/input.php` file yet?

Comment: Yes, since i didnt setup any proxy it comes down to this: `$this->ip_address = $this->server('remote_addr');`. When I tested `$this->input->server('remote_addr');` the strangest thing happened, first load it gave me an IP. The same IP as `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`, and when i reloaded it stopped returning an IP. not sure what to make of that...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41977/discussion-between-dvir-levy-and-monkeyzeus)

Comment: did you check that one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491043/retrieve-real-ip-of-user-using-codeigniter

Comment: @shuvo that gave me Message: Undefined index: HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, Im not sure how it happened, but apparently the var "`REMOTE_ADDR`" was coming in lowercase and should be uppercase. So adding `strtoupper()` to `input->server()`
on the var `$index` fixed my problem for now....

Very strange issue...

Answer (score 1):

`input->ip_address()` is defined incorrectly in system/core/input.php. 
On line 351 change it to `$this->ip_address = $this->server('REMOTE_ADDR');`